# SQL Server : Select TOP 10 Column based on SELECT TOP 100 Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 3 tables A, B, C

- A has ID and Name columns
- B has ID and PIN columns
- C has Name and Amount columns

In order to get the total amount of the top 10 PINs, I'm using:

```
SELECT TOP 10 PIN, SUM(Amount) AS PIN_Amount 
FROM A, B, C 
WHERE
    C.Name IN(A.Name) AND (A.ID = B.ID)
GROUP BY PIN
ORDER BY PIN_Amount DESC
```

How can I get only the TOP 100 Amount of the top 10 PINs?

Here's my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[A](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](10) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_A] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[B](
    [ID] [int] NULL,
    [PIN] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[C](
    [Name] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [Amount] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_C] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Name] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: What do YOU mean by the "TOP 100 Amount of the top 10 PINs"?  Why aren't you using `JOIN`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff There can be hundreds or thousands of C.Amount connected to a PIN, so I'm trying to SELECT only the TOP 100 SUM(Amount) of the TOP 10 PINs. I've been messing with it for days, tried JOIN but sadly I cannot figure it out.

Comment: What does TOP (100) SUM(Amount) mean?  If you SUM it then you only have 1 value per PIN.   Do you actually mean SUM(TOP 100 Largest Amounts) per PIN?

Comment: @MartinCairney SUM(TOP 100 Largest Amounts) per PIN , correct.

Comment: @Nikos: Did you get your answer?? If not, Can you tell me that `NAME` field between Table-A & Table-C can be joined?? Will it be unique for join?

Comment: @Irfan Not solved yet. Yes NAME can be joined and it's unique.

Comment: @Nikos: I have posted the query in the answers below! Please try

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`common_table_expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to achieve it.

```
;WITH cte_TempTable AS (
  SELECT TOP 10 PIN, SUM(Amount) AS PIN_Amount 
  FROM A
  INNER JOIN B ON  A.ID = B.ID
  INNER JOIN C ON  C.Name = A.Name
  GROUP BY PIN
  ORDER BY PIN_Amount DESC)

SELECT TOP 100 C.Amount 
FROM A
  INNER JOIN B ON  A.ID = B.ID
  INNER JOIN C ON  C.Name = A.Name
INNER JOIN cte_TempTable ON cte_TempTable.PIN =  B.PIN 
ORDER BY C.Amount DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Sadly I'm not familiar with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 so I gotta spend some time on it. Based on several stackoverflow searches that I did in the past, this one could work but at its current I cannot get a result, the query does not get complete, the execution goes on forever. Do you mind explaining what you meant by "-- join condition here" ?

Comment: Thanks for the update! On 2nd select there's no join for table A, it's giving me multi-part identifier bound issues (A.Name). I'll get some sleep because I've spent hours today trying to solve this, I'm sure that the solution is quite obvious thanks to your assistance but a headache is killing me right now. I'll take a look on it again tomorrow and if everything's correct I'll accept this answer as problem's solution. Thanks!

Comment: My bad. Please check again.

Comment: Unless I have misunderstood the OP, this solution will not work as it gets the top 100 amounts AFTER getting the top 10 totals. My understanding is that the OP wants only to include the top 100 amounts in identifying which are then the top 10 PINs. You would need to consider your CTE the other way round.  Using the tables in my repro this returns 100 rows, each with the Anmount = 1

Comment: @MartinCairney is right, this one selects the top 100 amounts no matter what. It should be selecting the TOP (100) SUM(Amount) for each of the TOP (10) PIN as mentioned on my original post.

Comment: Did you check my answer? Does this answer your question @Nikos

Comment: @Phong Yeah I replied above, "this one selects the top 100 amounts no matter what. It should be selecting the TOP (100) SUM(Amount) for each of the TOP (10) PIN as mentioned on my original post."

Answer (score 0):

My repro that shows the SUM as 100

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.A ([ID] int IDENTITY (1,1), [Name] varchar(10))
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.B (ID INT, PIN INT)
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.C ([Name] varchar(10), [Amount] INT)
GO

-- This inserts 1000 rows into table C 
DECLARE @counter INT = 1
WHILE @counter <= 1000
BEGIN
    INSERT dbo.C ([Name], [Amount]) 
    VALUES ('Test', 1)
    SELECT @counter += 1
END
GO

-- This inserts 1 record in Table A
INSERT dbo.A ([Name])
VALUES ('Test')
GO

-- This inserts 1 row in table B and ensures that the ID valu is
-- the same as table A
INSERT dbo.B (ID, PIN)
SELECT ID, 1234
FROM dbo.A
GO

SELECT TOP(10) PIN, SUM(D.Amount) as PIN_Amount
FROM A
JOIN B on A.ID = B.ID
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP (100) Amount FROM C WHERE Name = A.Name ORDER BY Amount DESC) D
GROUP BY PIN
ORDER BY PIN_Amount DESC
```

This results in the output:

```
PIN         PIN_Amount
1234    100
```

This is as expected totally the top 100 values from C

Comment: Sadly this one does not work, it's still showing the total amount of the PIN instead of TOP (100). Somehow TOP (100) is being ignored. Let's say 1000 rows are connected with PIN 1234 and each row has Amount 1. With TOP (100) it should be showing 1234 | 100 but for whatever reason that I cannot figure it out it's still showing the full Amount which is 1000.

Comment: Are you sure?   If I attempt a repro then I get PIN_Amount =100.  See my other answer for my repro steps.  If you are getting something different then you will need to share sample data that you are working with that gets your result

Comment: Indeed your repro is working fine but that's because (due to the lack of information from my side) I did not mention the PK's A.ID and C.Name

Comment: Well without you providing the full details - i.e. provide the schema and some sample data - then this is impossible to assist you with.

Comment: I did but i didn't get approved, someone deleted it... I've just edited my original post again with proper queries for creating the tables.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you!

```
SELECT AID, ANAME, BPIN, C2.AMOUNT
(
    SELECT TOP 10 A.ID AID, A.NAME ANAME, B.PIN BPIN
    FROM A INNER JOIN B
    ON A.ID = B.ID
    --ORDER BY YOUR_COLUMN_IN_CASE
) AS A2
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT NAME,AMOUNT,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Name) AS ROW_ID
    FROM C
    --ORDER BY NAME,YOUR_COLUMN_IN_CASE
) AS C2
ON A2.ANAME = C2.NAME
WHERE C2.ROW_ID < 101;
```

`ORDER BY` in both subqueries, you can modify as per your `TOP10` & `TOP100` requirements!

Answer (score 0):

From SQL Server 2012 onwards, you can use OFFSET... FETCH operator.[Read more on OFFSET FETCH](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2362/overview-of-offset-and-fetch-feature-of-sql-server-2012/)

I would suggest you to use ANSI JOIN syntax.

```
SELECT B.PIN, SUM(C.Amount) AS total_amount
FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID
INNER JOIN C ON A.Name = C.Name 
GROUP BY B.PIN
ORDER BY total_amount
OFFSET 0 ROWS
FETCH 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

For earlier versions of SQL Server, you can use TOP clause.

```
SELECT TOP 10 B.PIN, SUM(C.Amount) AS total_amount
FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID
INNER JOIN C ON A.Name = C.Name 
GROUP BY B.PIN
ORDER BY total_amount;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, but I'm using MS SQL 2008.

Comment: This is the same query as in my original post, it doesn't return TOP 100 SUM(C.Amount) of TOP 10 B.PIN